# Access array in before plugin to push data to it?

Tags: magento2, plugin

This is the original function I'm trying to write a plugin for:

```
  public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    ....
}
```

`$data` is an array.

In my plugin I want to add name to this array.

```
    public function beforeExecute()
{
     $data["name"] = "John";
}
```

If I add `$data["name"] = "John";` directly to the `execute function` it works (only for testing of course).

How to push data to the `$data` array in before plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortuantally you don't have much choice there in your example.

Create before plugin, and inside that plugin class add to your constructor:

```
public function __construct(Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Then you can add to your plugin:

```
public function beforeExecute()
{
     $params = $this->request->getParams();
     $params["name"] = "John";
     $this->request->setParams($params);

     return [];
}
```

**Request params manipulation should be avoided if possible**. Maybe there is better place inside your execute function to create plugin and manipulate data somewhere else.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much. I was trying since 2 days, because I couldn't figure it out. I still have to understand how this works, so I will dive deeper into it. As for your suggestion to avoid this solution: Unfortunately all other functions are private, so I can only hook into the execute function and into this array. Anyway, thank you very much.